# Get other files than .cs with Roslyn

Tags: c#, code-analysis, roslyn

I want to find usages of a method with `Roslyn`. I managed to do this for usages by code in the `.cs` files. Additionally I want to analyze JavaScript files included in the solution. I know that Roslyn cannot analyze syntax or sematics of JavaScript, so I only want to search for `textural occurrencies` of my method's name in all `.js` files.

I retrieve all files (documents) like this:

```
foreach (Project pr in solution.Projects)
{
    foreach (Document doc in pr.Documents)
    {
      // my js-file is not included
    }
}
```

But `Documents` only contains `.cs` files. Is there a way to get also `.js` files or do I have to get the folder with `project.FilePath` and get the files with the old `File API`, which could cause problems because not necessarily all files in the folder must have been added to the project etc.?

Edit:
Also `AdditionalFiles` does not hold any file.

Comment: Isn't there a `AdditionalFiles` property available for this?

Comment: It does not contain any item

Comment: You need to use the MSBuild APIs directly, without Roslyn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`Project.AdditionalDocuments`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs,f431d91b27009921,references):

```
foreach (Project pr in solution.Projects) {
    foreach (TextDocument doc in pr.AdditionalDocuments) {
      // doc is a non-csharp TextDocument object.
    }
}
```

#### Update

To use the above you must ensure that the file in the target project has its build action set to `AdditionalFiles`. There is no good way currently to generate a file in the target project with a build action of this type so you are currently stuck with relying on the user of your code manually creating a stub of the file, hitting `F4` for the file properties and changing its build action to `AdditionalFiles`, after which your extension will be able to pick it up.

[image: AdditionalFiles]

Comment: I had thought the same but it is empty. I tried "Content", "Resource" and "Embedded Resource" for the .js file but no success

Comment: @FlatEric - I actually just ran into the same issue. I still think the code is right but seems like there is a missing piece that hydrates the `AdditionalDocuments` object within a vsix package (my use case). I'm able to call `project.AddAdditionalDocument` with a TypeScript file and it creates it perfectly. I'm determined to figure this out, will update my answer when I get something that works.

Comment: @FlatEric got it figured out for my needs and updated post.